# Механизм генерации роутов в шаблонах в spring mvc приложении

Tags: spring, java, маршрутизация

Нужен механизм генерации роутов в шаблонах в spring mvc приложении.

т.е. в шаблоне указывается конструкция вида

```
<a href="<route:route controller="MainController.index", parameters={page: 1}/>">main page</a>
```

и получаем результат в виде сгенерированной ссылки

```
<a href="/main/?page=1">main page</a>
```

В спринг как я понял готового механизма роутинга нет, какой лучше плагин использовать ?

Comment: А в Spring разве есть плагины?!

Comment: Да, отсутствие механизма генерации URL по связке controller/action — большая проблема Spring Web MVC. Но и самостоятельная реализация этого — задача не слишком сложная, за вечер вполне себе пишется. Ну или же ждать реализации [соответствующей задачи][1], которая уже назначена на v4.1.

  [1]: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-5779

Comment: не плагины, а сторонние библиотеки

Answer (score 1):

В принципе вот так url'ы правильно генерятся, с учетом названия приложения, если приложение мапится на url типа http://localhost:8080/app/

```
<spring:url value="/category/{slug}" var="articleUrl">
    <spring:param name="slug" value="${category.name}" />
</spring:url>

<a href="${articleUrl}">${category.name}</a>
```